# grabbing a character at a given position

Tags: python, string

```
s: five - letter string
psn: an int between 0 and 4
return: result the character that is at position psn in s

def index_string(s,psn):
   position = psn -1
   return s[position]
```

I don't know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first line, as Python strings are indexed starting with 0:

```
def index_string(s, psn):
   return s[psn]

s = index_string('March', 2)
print(s == 'r')
```

https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types